# Literature on path from industry (STEM, not CS) to academia

Tags: industry

I got my PhD 5 years ago and went straight to industry. Currently in industry and loving it, I'm in 30s.

At some point I want to move back to academia. I think sharing industry experience and helping students with networking in industry is what is badly missing in the current STEM academia. That's what I was missing form my adviser and heard lots of students are missing.

I plan to return to academia in my 50s.

Are there anything to read to prepare myself for this? Any blogs/books/personal experience is greatly appreciated!

Questions in the comments:

1. Are you doing research in industry?

Yes, R&D.

2. What aspects do you think you need to prepare for?

How to bring money in and interact with colleagues (professors), I guess.

Comment: Since you aren't planning to return for 10-20 years, it seems a little early to prepare. Regardless, what aspects do you think you need to prepare for?

Comment: You could start _sharing industry experience and helping students with networking in industry_ now: Get yourself an honorary position at a university (with whom you have ties) and start now. As a bonus, that'd surely smooth any future transition back into academia.

Comment: Are you doing research in industry?

Comment: > what aspects do you think you need to prepare for?
I guess how to bring money in and communicate with colleagues (other professors)

> Are you doing research in industry?
R&D, yes.

Comment: You aren't asking for advice here beyond existing literature on the subject. That is limiting answers, perhaps. I don't have literature, but might have advice.